# Are heavy selectors in CSS readable?

Tags: css

Take the below code that I recently wrote:

```
.navbar-inverse .emphasis-text, .navbar-inverse:hover .emphasis-text, .emphasis-text {
    color: #1caa98; /* Teal */
}
```

While this may be a *dryer* way of placing teal on all these link items, would you consider this readable? It seems to me like there is a lot to read, and it's not entirely clear what these are for. It's okay if this is fine, but it would be nice to hear some opinions from outside my own eyeballs.

Comment: The DRY solution would be `.emphasis-text { color: #1caa98; /* Teal */ }`.  It may or may not work correctly, depending on what other style rules there are. It's hard to write a meaningful review on such a short excerpt. If there weren't already an answer posted, I'd be tempted to close this question as [generic or hypothetical](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1709/9357).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Not really

I think that's about as succinct as it will get. You could improve readability somewhat with some line breaks though, like this:

```
.navbar-inverse .emphasis-text, 
.navbar-inverse:hover .emphasis-text, 
.emphasis-text {
    color: #1caa98; /* Teal */
}
```